# Добавление в массив $_FILES ранее загруженного файла с сервера

Tags: php, wordpress

На сервере лежит раннее загруженный и обработанный файл, есть ли способ добавить этот файл в массив `$_FILES` для дальнейшей обработки?
В общем, есть форма добавления записи для пользователя на сайте. В форме есть обработчик картинок, который при загрузке картинки пользователем, обрабатывает ее и загружает AJAXом на сервер в нужную мне папку и возвращает путь до загруженного файла. Далее пользователь заполняет форму добавления записи и отправляет ее POSTом в обработчик. Принимая данные от пользователя мне нужно добавить ранее загруженный файл и массив `$_FILES`.

Answer (score 2):

Не стоит этого делать.
Если файл уже загружен и обработан, работай далее уже с сохранённым файлом, `$_FILES` - лишь абстракция для загружаемого файла, создаваемая сервером; с существующим это тоже можно сделать (переместить файл в временную папку и добавить все обычные поля в `$_FILES` ручками), но лучше включить мозг обратно и работать с тем, что уже обработано.